# Is disturbing the flow of elements in a CSS grid an appropriate use of the system?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am learning [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) and realized that it is possible to decorrelate the flow of my elements in HTML from the actual rendering via CSS Grid. I am wondering if this is a supported approach (or, put differently, if this is a by-design behaviour).

In the code below, the three `div` can be moved around the grid by just changing their class:

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "header header" 
    "left right";
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
}

.left {
  grid-area: left;
}

.right {
  grid-area: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="header">one</div>
  <div class="right">two</div>
  <div class="left">three</div>
</div>
```

Swapping the classes in the two last `div` switches their positioning.

Such an approach would free me from building my page according to the flow of the DOM elements, and rather have a stack of components one after the others, ordered via their classes.

This is very much different from the approach I had so far (a very amateur one), in which the order of the components in the HTML part were driving the rendering (actual placement) order.

**Is this approach of disconnecting the order of components in the HTML section from the final order in the browser thanks to CSS Grid correct?** (correct = expected behaviour according to the CSS design, and not a side effect of the grid system)

Comment: When not using your abstract left/right naming, having this order actually can make sense in a site with `rtl` language support. And Allowing for a change of order is not a new thing just for grid. It can also be done by setting `order` in `flex` or `grid`, by `floats` or by any `position` with a value other than `static`. In general though, you should try to keep a logical HTML structure, mainly for screen readers and keyboard users in general.

Comment: @René: thanks for the input. I am mostly asking because with this separation between the HTML flow and the actual placement, components (such as `div` in my example) become more like functions, in the sense that their order does not matter, they are just stacked one on each other, and the parameter (`class` in that case) drives their behaviour (= placement).

Comment: I might not grasp the whole meaning of your question. I would say the order is just as important as it ever was, you just got a few extra options to change that **visually**. But changing it drastically is confusing for developers, keyboard users and search engines. You also still have to think about nesting of elements. Fun fact, `tfoot` must be placed between `thead` and `tbody` but visually always shows at the bottom to be ideal for both visual as non visual users.

Comment: @René - While I fully support your comment about the dangers of visually reordering content to non-visual users, and this applies to flexbox as well as grid, you should note that the order of the thead, tfoot and tbody elements is changed in HTML5 from what it was in HTML 4.01, and that since HTML 5.1 the only valid order is thead, tbody, tfoot.

Comment: @René: I understand the concern for developers and possibly search engines (which maybe expect the HTML flow to be aligned with the visual placement) but keyboard users?

Comment: @Alohci Thanks, I already had a bit of renewed doubt so I searched it and the first reference I found was fairly recent and I just fell for it :-( I don't think I even placed any tfoot between in the last 5 years. Browsers fix it anyway.

Comment: @WoJ - I'd be more concerned by screen reader users in general, than sighted keyboard users, but you should check the tab order of elements in your reordered content to make sure that it doesn't jump around seemingly randomly. Also check in different browsers, as they may not all do the same thing.

Comment: @WoJ Yes, when you use tab or shift+tab you expect your next focus to arrive at the next link or input element(or general focusable element), if you drastically change the order the focus will jump all the way around. If you place your footer first in html the first tab will bring you to the first link in the footer. (and people with screen readers are probably keyboard users, so keyboard users is the overall term)

Comment: @René: the `Tab` behaviour is a very good point. I just tested this (https://codepen.io/WoJWoJ/pen/vpeBdg) and indeed, the input is jumping all over the place. I will have this in mind, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML and CSS are already disconnected by design. There should be no correlation, because they each serve a different purpose.

The HTML exists to build documents that are structured logically and semantically, and accessible by all people on the internet, regardless of device or disability.

So an HTML document needs to consider the needs of people with visual impairments and those using screen readers, text-only browsers or tab navigation.

An HTML document should also factor in search engine algorithms.

Basically, HTML targets any person or machine that will access your page.

CSS has a different and much more limited focus: It creates the visual style of a web page.

By altering the HTML in order to conform with the CSS, *you* are establishing the correlation and ignoring the needs of non-visual users.

Comment: Michael: while I appreciate your answer (and all the others you were very helpful with), I feel that the last part is quite harsh. The app I am building is a display-only dashboard, without any keyboard and without anyone else than me accessing it (= looking at it). So *me* ignoring the needs of disabled people is quite a stretch.This said, thanks for the HTML vs CSS perspective, which is enlightening (especially the HTML part and its general intended use).

Comment: I didn't mean to sound harsh. But I can see now how the last line can be interpreted as an accusation. Apologies. I was trying to emphasize a general point in relation to your question. It wasn't personal, as I didn't know your use-case and I write answers for the community, not individual people. Cheers!

Comment: No worries, no hard feelings - the explanation about the HTML section was really enlightening.